# How to sort Array with date as key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this:

```
array:6 [▼
 "2016-07-28" => array:18 [▶]
 "2016-07-29" => array:18 [▶]
 "2016-07-30" => array:5 [▶]
 "2016-07-31" => array:5 [▶]
 "2016-08-01" => array:17 [▶]
 "2016-08-02" => array:11 [▶]
]
```

I know want to revert the order, having `2016-08-02` the first and `2016-07-28` the last entry.

**I tried**

```
asort($missingArr);
```

**Result**

```
array:6 [▼
 "2016-07-29" => array:18 [▶]
 "2016-07-28" => array:18 [▶]
 "2016-08-01" => array:17 [▶]
 "2016-08-02" => array:11 [▶]
 "2016-07-31" => array:5 [▶]
 "2016-07-30" => array:5 [▶]
]
```

Even when converting the date to a unix timestamp it does the exact same thing. Where am I wrong?

Comment: http://php.net/ksort

Comment: You could try `ksort` for timestamp array keys

Comment: asort is for sorting with value, ksort() is for sorting with key asc ,krsort() for sort desc, here date is the key

Comment: This might be [helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date), by using the same concept you can approach your solution as well.

Comment: you could just use `sort()` I use that when I am working with AWS which is what they require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) *(k stands for "key", r for "reverse")*:

```
krsort($missingArr);
```